# ionic2 html page button bottom

Tags: css, html, ionic2

**page.html**

```
<div padding class="about-info">
      <a ion-button color="light" href="tel:1800889958">
      立即拨打
      </a>
</div>
```

This is a number calling function, and I ald set in scss put it at the bottom of the page, but function not showing.

**page.scss**

```
.about-info {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #F44336;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%;
}
.about-info a{
  vertical-align: bottom;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your best option is to use the [footer component](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/toolbar/Footer/):

```
<ion-content></ion-content>

<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Footer</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Comment: This one I try ald.. but it's different type with my code style